# Wifi and android app comunication

Tags: android, android-wifi, serial-communication

hi i am working on a app in which i want to send some kind of data to my connected WiFi  device.so how can i do that and if i want to use it remotely so what i require i try to communicate with WiFi but i am unable to connect or pair with it

```
public static String ipAddress;// ur ip
    public static int portNumber;// portnumber

    private Socket client;

    private OutputStreamWriter printwriter;
    private String message;


new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            client = new Socket(ipAddress, portNumber);
                            printwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(client
                                    .getOutputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");
                            printwriter.write("any message");
                            printwriter.flush();
                            printwriter.close();
                            client.close();
                        }

                        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

What errors you get?

To make your posted code work you probably have to take Internet permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET

Additionally, if you need do it only on wifi check for wifi first (and request appropriate permission in manifest)